# Firebase won't send push notifications to all live iOS app users

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification

Perhaps a silly questions, but here it goes. 
We are using Firebase to send out our notifications for an iOS app. When we send notifications, it appears that not all live, iOS app users are receiving the notifications.

We have targeted all users who has installed the app, but it appears that minorities aren't receiving the notification.

The notification works are all development phones without any issues.

Has anyone else experienced this and if so, why are some live iOS app users not receiving our notification sends?

Comment: Are you sure you have the production certificates used with the PNS?

Comment: Get very familiar with this doc https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2265/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

Basically if your development devices are receiving the PN's then you are using development Push certificates from your Push Notification Server. You need to have your production ones installed in order to send. You also have to ship production ones with the app. Very easy to get them from Apples developer site and install them just the same as the dev ones.

Otherwise like I said in the comments get very familiar with [TN2265](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2265/_index.html)

Comment: We have got a separate development project with developer push notification certificate. We have a separate live one with a production certificate that's been released to the app store